# gnuplot load/eval nested too deeply on 'pause -1'

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my gnuplot file. (/tmp/plot.gnuplot)

```
set datafile separator ','
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set term x11 background rgb "white" size 1000,1000
set xtics rotate
plot '~/SA.Ring.write.cvs' using 6:(strcol(8) eq "OSTimeNS"?$7:NaN) with linespoints
pause -1
```

When I run it with `gnuplot -p /tmp/plot.gnuplot` I get the following error:

```
"/tmp/plot.gnuplot" line 8: load/eval nested too deeply
```

if I try to resize, zoom or otherwise interact with the canvas. The canvas is rendered properly initially.

line 8 is the `pause -1` line.

Line 7 is the only complicated line. Basically I wanted gnuplot to "only use cvs rows where the 8th column is equal to OSTimeNS, then use column 6 and 7 as (X,Y)"

The cvs file is some 50,000 lines, but it renders instantly.

How can I interact with this plot and avoid the load/eval error?

Thanks.

EDIT:

gnuplot-5.4.1-r1   Gentoo Linux

Use flags:

```
[ Legend : U - final flag setting for installation]
[        : I - package is installed with flag     ]
[ Colors : set, unset                             ]
 * Found these USE flags for sci-visualization/gnuplot-5.4.1-r1:
 U I
 + + X                        : Add support for X11
 - - bitmap                   : Enable dot-matrix printers and pbm terminal 
 + + cairo                    : Enable support for the cairo graphics library
 - - doc                      : Add extra documentation (API, Javadoc, etc). It is recommended to enable per package instead of globally
 - - examples                 : Install examples, usually source code
 + + gd                       : Add support for media-libs/gd. Needed for GIF, JPEG, and PNG image output.
 - - ggi                      : Add support for media-libs/libggi (non-X video api/drivers)
 - - latex                    : Add support for LaTeX (typesetting package)
 - - libcaca                  : Add support for colored ASCII-art graphics
 - - libcerf                  : Enable special functions from sci-libs/libcerf
 - - lua                      : Enable Lua scripting support
 + + lua_single_target_lua5-1 : Build for Lua 5.1 only
 - - lua_single_target_lua5-3 : Build for Lua 5.3 only
 - - qt5                      : Add support for the Qt 5 application and UI framework
 + + readline                 : Enable support for libreadline, a GNU line-editing library that almost everyone wants
 - - regis                    : Enable ReGIS terminal 
 - - wxwidgets                : Add support for wxWidgets/wxGTK GUI toolkit
```

The error goes away if I use a ~500 row cvs file. Even 1000 rows is too much!

Comment: which version of gnuplot are you running on which operating system?

Comment: @theozh edits completed.

Comment: so far, I cannot reproduce this with Win10, gnuplot 5.4.1,wxt terminal ... Why do you need `pause -1` at the end? The option `gnuplot -p` (or `--persist`) is for keeping the plot window open after plotting. Do you have another loop which you don't show here?

Comment: I've found that switching to the QT terminal solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am mystified as to why you get that error message.  It supposedly is triggered only when a script loads itself recursively, but your script does not do that.

One thing you could try is to replace the line `pause -1` with a different command `pause mouse close` and invoke the script without the `-p` option. You should then be able to interact with the plot until you close the window with a mouse or hot-key action.